# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: maven, selenium

[image: Project Structure]

I am trying to run pom.xml using cmd but when i am using the command as mvn install I am getting the following error , the first one is the POM.XML while the second is the attached cmd result window , please check

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tiger</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SampleProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.48.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- //for Reportng(guice ,velocity is added) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>

                    <!-- <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
 -->
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <!-- <reporting> <plugins> TestNG-xslt related configuration. <plugin> <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId> 
        <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId> <version>1.2</version> <configuration> 
        Output directory for the testng xslt report <outputDir>/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir> 
        <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks> <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter> 
        <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals> </configuration> </plugin> </plugins> 
        </reporting> -->


</project>
```

CMD:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tiger</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SampleProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.48.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- //for Reportng(guice ,velocity is added) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>

                    <!-- <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
 -->
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <!-- <reporting> <plugins> TestNG-xslt related configuration. <plugin> <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId> 
        <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId> <version>1.2</version> <configuration> 
        Output directory for the testng xslt report <outputDir>/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir> 
        <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks> <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter> 
        <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals> </configuration> </plugin> </plugins> 
        </reporting> -->


</project>
 CMD RESULT:


C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\SampleProject>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SampleProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be ava
ilable, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be ava
ilable, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be ava
ilable, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\SampleProject\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\SampleProject\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\SampleProject\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Shashank_bisht/workspace/SampleProject/src/main/java/tiger/Marketing/CreateLeadPage.java:[8,4
7] package tiger.SampleProject.MyHomepageTestCases does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.252 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-16T16:01:57+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on
project SampleProject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Shashank_bisht/workspace/SampleProject/src/main/java/tiger/Marketing/CreateLeadPage.java:[8,4
7] package tiger.SampleProject.MyHomepageTestCases does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error log, it looks like the CreatingLeadPage.java is trying to import tiger.SampleProject.MyHomepageTestCases class which it is unable to find since this class might not be present as a part of your source code.
You should add this class file to compile your code.

Comment: Ok the thing is that I have two folders src/main/java and src/test/java , what maven is doing it is directing to src/main/java and not to src/test/java where my test classes are , how cna i point the maven to execute the test classes instead of going into src/main/java ?Just to refer I have added the picture of my Folder structure above , pls see image above.Thanks